# How many power bi Embed tokens have been generated?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have Power BI embedded reports with dedicated capacity. We now want to see usage of these. I'd like to be able to see how many embed tokens are generated each day. I can't find any details on this in the documentation or APIs.

In the standard Report usage metrics, all the stats are against a single user - because it's the website connecting to the report. Does anyone know the best way to report on per-user usage of embedded reports?

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you what you want is possible. Once you have purchased a dedicated capacity, there is no limit to how many embed tokens you can generate.

You could have a look at the [AdditionalFeatureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/availablefeatures/getavailablefeaturebyname)

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/availableFeatures(featureName='{featureName}')
```

> Returns the token generation usage (in %) from the limitation on
> shared capacity

There is also a number of endpoints for usage of reports you could have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports